# Checking for Summed Zeros Sets

Tags: algorithm

I was asked by a friend to answer a small challenge and if we could find an optimal solution. The challenge being, given a random set of negative and positive numbers, `ie. (-10, -7, -4, -3, 1, 4, 4, 6, 12)`  how can we create an efficient algorithm for the sets of positive and negative numbers that equate to 0 leaving the fewest unused numbers left over?

> example: given set (-10, -7, -4, -3, 1, 4, 4, 6, 12)
>
> possible sets of 0: {-10, -7, 1, 4, 12}, {-4, 4}
>
> left over numbers: {-3, 6}

A few ideas were to try dynamic programming, but I foresee issues with running into large timeframes for completion. Another idea was to try and create a linear program with all numbers lined in one set and create subsets attempting to reach 0, this ran into issues where previous negative numbers could have been used but were ignored unless a for loop was used to reiterate over negative numbers when the value was over 0.

Comment: So what is you question?

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Nah, that about answers my question. I didn't look to see if it was NP hard as I was trying to solve it more currently on my own. So it seems, no matter the algorithm, its going to run exponential. The question being for an efficient algorithm to find sets of 0, but the algorithms I formulated kept going exponential and I didn't know if others had ideas to avoid it.

Comment: @EvilDrCoconut This is sometimes known as the easiest hard problem.  Because it is NP-complete but the dynamic programming solution runs in pseudo-polynomial time which in practice is quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given by Ezequiel Muns, this is an NP-Complete problem called Subset sum problem (more can be found at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

I was attempting to work my own ideas before looking up a solution, but after asking a few others about this, it seems I ran into a NP-Hard problem without realizing it. I had simply thought my own algorithms were inefficient and someone perhaps had a better solution.